# How to "denormalise" XML using Qt

Tags: xslt, xpath, qt5, xquery, qxmlquery

Is there a tutorial or even an example on QXQuery or XSLT in qt how to transform the first XML code in the second?
Currently I do it manually in C++. I guess QXQuery would do it with few lines, but I can't figure out how?

XML1
 Basically I want to move all information from corresponding types of ITEMTYPE to ITEMS.

```
  <ITEMTYPES>
    <ITEMTYPE type="X">
       <Color>Red</Color>
       <Size>100</Size>
    </ITEMTYPE>

    <ITEMTYPE type="Y">
       <Color>Green</Color>
       <Size>200</Size>
    </ITEMTYPE>

    <ITEMTYPE type="Z">
       <Color>Yellow</Color>
       <Size>150</Size>
    </ITEMTYPE>

  </ITEMTYPES>
</ROOT>
```

XML2

```
<ROOT>
  <ITEMS>
    <ITEM>
       <Color>Red</Color>
       <Size>100</Size>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
       <Color>Green</Color>
       <Size>200</Size>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
       <Color>Yellow</Color>
       <Size>150</Size>
    </ITEM>
  </ITEMS>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: This is trivial to do in XSLT. Spend an hour with a tutorial and you will know how.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Looks like Qt5 indeed provides XSLT. Thanks!